# Applying gradients with feed_dict for gradients

Tags: tensorflow

I want to do some non-tensorflow processing on the computed gradients, before applying them on the variables.

My plan was to run the gradient ops that I get from the `compute_gradients` function , do my processing (in python without tensorflow), and then run the apply operation I get from the `apply_gradients` function and feed the processed gradients in the `feed_dict`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work in my scenario.

I managed to narrow it down to some issue with `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` (same happens with `tf.gather`), and the error can be reproduced as follows (using tf1.4):

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[])
z = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[])
emb_mat = tf.get_variable('w', [100, 5], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
emb = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb_mat, z)
loss = x - tf.reduce_sum(emb) # Just some silly loss

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())
train_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
grads = [g for g,v in grads_and_vars]

tsess = tf.Session()
tsess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
gradsres = tsess.run(grads, {x: 1.0, z: 1})
tsess.run(train_op, {g:r for g,r in zip(grads, gradsres)})
```

which results in the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cruvadom/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_6.0.0.201709191431/pysrc/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1098, in _run
    raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("gradients/Gather_1_grad/ToInt32:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32, device=/device:GPU:0) may not be fed.
```

It seems there is some additional tensor I need to feed to the graph for the computation. What is the right way to do why I want to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you run the training operation, it will automatically calculate the gradients. You can retrieve the gradients from the session:

```
    tsess = tf.Session()
    tsess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    _, grads_and_vars, loss = tsess.run([train_op ,grads, loss], {x: 1.0, z: 1})
    assert not np.isnan(loss), 'Something wrong! loss is nan...'

    #Get the gradients
    for g, v in grads_and_vars:
        if g is not None:
            grad_hist_summary = tf.summary.histogram("{}/grad_histogram".format(v.name), g)
            sparsity_summary = tf.summary.scalar("{}/grad/sparsity".format(v.name), tf.nn.zero_fraction(g))
```

Comment: I don't want to run the train op before I process the gradients

Comment: I think you can do  sess.run([grads], {x: 1.0, z: 1}) to get the gradients before running train_op